# In Sconstruct, how can I specify include paths for D programming language

Tags: d, scons

Seems that CPPPATH does not work

```
env = Environment()
target = 'app'
sources = ['app.d']
libs = ['phobos2', 'pthread', 'm', 'rt']
includes = ['/home/supertool/devel/d/vibe.d/source/vibe']

env.Program(target = target,
        source = sources,
        LIBS = libs,
        CPPPATH = includes);
```

and when I run scons, it generates compile command:

```
dmd -I. -c -ofapp.o app.d
```

`includes` is not added into `-I` part

So how can I config this? Is there a INCLUDEPATH ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `CPPPATH` construction variable, for which SCons prepends the `-I`, you could try *manually* building the paths, like this:

```
includePaths = ['-Ipath1', '-Ipath2']
....
env.Program(target = target,
            source = sources,
            LIBS = libs,
            CCFLAGS = includePaths);
```

But this may lead to the same problem, that `CCFLAGS` wont be used for `D` compilation. I havent seen any D-specific construction variables other than `DSUFFIXES`

**EDIT**: Looks like `DFLAGS` and `DPATH` are not documented

I was playing around with this on my machine and see that `CCFLAGS` wont work for `D`, but `DFLAGS` and `DPATH` do, and they're not documented :( `DPATH` will have `"I"` prepended at compile time, so it is analogous to `CPPPATH`

There has been talk on the SCons user mail list about beefing up the SCons D support.